# Flattening array, but excluding root element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array and only want to flatten/concatenate the items starting under the root, excluding the root level.

With Array.flat() you can specify the depth, but not the starting level. Is there a smart way to accomplish what I want?

```
let measures = Object
    .entries(schemaMetadataCache)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(foo => foo.ColumnType === 2)]);

console.log(measures); // non flattened
console.log(measures.flat(2)); // flattened, but need to exclude root level
```

Array before flattening [image: Original array]

After flattening, I only wanted the 12 items.

[image: After flattening]

Comment: why don't you loop the main array and merge first index of each element of array? As I can see that it is 2d Array.

Comment: can you provide the input data and expected output, in that way other members can provide you with working example.

Comment: For those commenting. The input data is as shown, the output data is as I clearly explained, a concatenated array with 12 items. I can indeed do a loop easily but I am under the assumption there is a one-liner that I might have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let measures = Object
    .entries(schemaMetadataCache)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(foo => foo.ColumnType === 2)]);
```

considering the above snippet and the expected result, why not return the flattened values instead?

```
let measures = Object
    .entries(schemaMetadataCache)
    .flatMap(([k, v]) => v.filter(foo => foo.ColumnType === 2));
```

Comment: The flatMap only flattens the complete result, you will still end up with an array containing the key. However your suggestion helped me solve it. I added the new code in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaSchopman I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not returning the key in the suggested solution.

Comment: You are right Ramesh. I overlooked you removed the key assignment as well. Thanks, and assigned the bounty to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want root arrays to be flattened, but not root elements (non arrays) to be included in the final result.

It is possible to create your own implementation of `Array.flat()` with min/max depth support, but for your specific case, that would be overkill.

Look at the following snippet for a possible solution.

```js
const input = [
  'valueA',
  'valueB',
  [{name: 'Object1', value: '1'}, {name: 'Object2', value: '2'}],
  [{name: 'Object3', value: '3'}],
  'valueC',
  0,
  true,
  [{name: 'Object4', value: '4'}, {name: 'Object5', value: '5'}]
];

const output = input.filter((item) => Array.isArray(item)).flat();

console.log(output);
```